# NullPointerException, Unsure what is causing null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am currently getting a crash in my application caused on line 53 Caused by (or that's what i gathered from logcat): `java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.mdpmk1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)`

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.mdpmk1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button bt1, bt2, bt3;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
                    bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);



                    bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
                            integrator.initiateScan();
                        }
                    });

                    bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, location1.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

   }

                    });



                    bt3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, location2.class);
                            startActivity(intent);


                        }
                    });

                }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
                    {
                        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                        if (requestCode == 0) {
                            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                            }
                        }
                    }


                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

            }
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/codeResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/appName"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I know that its pointing at my third button but to my knowledge there is nothing wrong with my code.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your `activity_main` layout doesn't contain the button(s).

Comment: @Zoran, Line 53 is ` bt3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`

Comment: Please provide your xml, it seems that bt3 doesn't exist in it or id is wrong

Comment: @laalto, I can visually see the buttons in eclipse display and i can see them in the code?

Comment: so post them so we can see

Comment: Clean and rebuild. Possibly the resource ids are out of sync after you edited a layout XML.

Comment: Do you get error when clicking on other two buttons?

Comment: @Tehjohn are you sure the posted xml is `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: @Zoran Other two buttons work fine.

Comment: @Raghunandan 110% sure

Comment: @Tehjohn then bt3 cannot be null. Post the stacktrace. The problem might be else where

Comment: @Raghunandan, Dont know what caused it but with a reboot of the emulator and a clean and rebuild the app doesnt crash on loading... But now the third button crashes the application. see "João Marcos" Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this line

```
bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

returns null on bt3.

Try to see if button3 is well defined (id) in your xml layout.

If its ok try to clean and build the project to re-generate the R file.

Note: if you make a little change in xml file the R file will be re-generated.

Comment: Cleaning and building the project didnt work first time, Restarted emulator and did it a second time and it now loads the `activity_main` but now crashes on click of `bt3`. Any clue why?

Comment: Nevermind, It was a simple R.id issue